# Archlinux vim access in tty1 for editing resolv.conf

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dns, vim, arch-linux

I installed Archlinux in Virtualbox and the installation has gone smoothly.

I faced issues in pacman - temporary name resolution failure. When I read online, one of the solution was to update the /etc/resolv.conf file. How do I edit this file ?

Below are the steps I did :
a) Checked ip link and my interface name is enps03.
b) Activated the interface using
`#ip link enps03 up`
c) Added ip address manually `# ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev enps03`
d) Added Gateway manually `# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1`

Changed the nameserver in resolv.conf using the echo command.

I am still not able to ping to the net.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

A working resolv.conf file consists of 1 line that just says `nameserver <ip address here>`. So you don't have to *edit* the file that's currently there – you can just completely overwrite it with new content like this:

```
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

The 'base' package installs a *very* minimal system, with no network configuration present by default (unlike the Arch ISO). Because you're not running a DHCP client, not only you don't have a DNS server configured, you *also* don't have an IP address and a default gateway configured either. You will need to add those using `ip addr` and `ip route` manually, or set up systemd-networkd get an address automatically from DHCP.

Comment: I have edited my question to fill in more details. I tried the above but I am still not able to ping to internet. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change or set the nameserver you can do that in this way:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Maybe you have a `vi` installed. Check.

Comment: I checked on vim. It says command not found. Funny since I used vim during installation. Also surprisingly sudo also shows as command not found

Comment: I wrote `vi`, not `vim`. If you are able to logon to root account you can do that: `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Sorry my bad - no even vi gives a command not found error.